# How to define that layout in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, grid

I expierience problem in defining(using `Grid`) layout which looks like that:

[image]

I know how to get simple layout which looks like that:

[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

**How to achieve that first layout?**

Answer (score 3):

<s>You can't achieve that with one Grid.</s> Create a Grid with 2 columns and 3 rows. Then put another Grid in row 1 column 1 of the outer Grid. For example (also demonstrating how to put control in each cell) :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label >Row 1 Column 1</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1">Row 2 Column 1</Label>
    </Grid>
    <Label >Row 0 Column 0</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1">Row 1 Column 0</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2">Row 2 Column 0</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1">Row 0 Column 1</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">Row 3 Column 1</Label>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE :**

Actually you can also achieve that with one Grid as suggested by @Chris in comment. Create a Grid with 2 columns and 4 rows. Then set UI control in row 1 column 0 to take up space for two rows (set `Grid.RowSpan="2"`). This is the example :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label >Row 0 Column 0</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">Row 1 Column 0</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="3">Row 2 Column 0</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1">Row 0 Column 1</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Row 1 Column 1</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">Row 2 Column 1</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">Row 3 Column 1</Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks but could you tell me how to insert an object in that inner(lower)cell. This the smallest cell . Lets say `Button`? Because it's coordinates are like `1.1x1.0` but I am sure it is not how I should refer to it.

Comment: replace `....` in my answer to your `Button`, you can also specify in which row of the inner Grid you want the Button placed.

Comment: He could do that with one grid easily by adding another row and making the contents of Row1 Column0 Grid.RowSpan="2" in case one grid was desired. Just as a side note.

Comment: @ChrisW. yes, you're right. I forgot about `RowSpan`. Updated my answer to include that option. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<Grid>        
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="50">
         <RowDefinition Height="70">
         <RowDefinition Height="300">
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="50">
         <RowDefinition Height="50">
         <RowDefinition Height="20">
         <RowDefinition Height="300">
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Just change the height and width as you want.